# Recieving an Argument out of range Exception when iterating through the contents of a DataGridView from a Test Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have been writing a stock keeping application for a programming course I have taken. One of the requirements for this assessment is the inclusion of two functioning unit tests. I have created two tests that worked before I did a rework of some of the code, and since then, they have stopped functioning. These tests are for two methods that use the values of cells within a DataGridView to determine whether or not they are considered "low stock". These methods function as intended, and run with no problems when the application is run normally, but throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException when run from the tests.

This is the first of the test methods. The error occurs within the settingsConfig.StockWarningToggle method, included below the test.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void GeneralStockWarningNonStandardNumbers()
    {
        var stockcounts = new List<string>() 
        {
            "-1",
            "0",
            "1",
            "2",
            "3",
            "4",
            "5",
            "6",
            "7",
            "8",
            "9",
            "10"
        };
        var tempForm = new Form();
        var tempDataGrid = new DataGridView();
        var inventoryData = new DataView();
        var settingsConfig = new SettingsConfiguration(SettingsConfiguration.listOfSettings, tempDataGrid, TestFilePaths.settingsFile);
        tempDataGrid.DefaultCellStyle = DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle;

        var dataFromFile = new DataTable("WSInventoryData");
        var tableColumn = new DataColumn("Item Code", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dataFromFile.Columns.Add(tableColumn);
        tableColumn = new DataColumn("Item Description", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dataFromFile.Columns.Add(tableColumn);
        tableColumn = new DataColumn("Current Count", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
        dataFromFile.Columns.Add(tableColumn);
        tableColumn = new DataColumn("On Order", Type.GetType("System.String"));
        dataFromFile.Columns.Add(tableColumn);

        foreach (var stockItem in stockcounts)
        {
            var row = dataFromFile.NewRow();
            row["Item Code"] = "";
            row["Item Description"] = "";
            row["Current Count"] = stockItem;
            row["On Order"] = "";
            dataFromFile.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        inventoryData.Table = dataFromFile;
        tempDataGrid.DataSource = inventoryData.Table;
        tempForm.Controls.Add(tempDataGrid);
        
        settingsConfig.StockWarningToggle(stockcounts, tempDataGrid, true);

        var textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 0];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
        textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 1];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
        textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 2];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
        textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 3];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
        textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 4];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
        textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 5];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
        textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 6];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
        textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 8];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
        textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 9];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
        textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 10];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
        textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 11];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
        textbox = tempDataGrid[2, 12];
        Assert.IsTrue(textbox.Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
    }
```

The error occurs when trying to locate the cell within the DataGridView to change its style property to DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle. However sometimes when running through in debug mode, the code executes as I would expect, and an exception is thrown at the 7th Assert statement in the test method. This seems to only happen when I have spent over a minute at that point with the code paused, but attempts to reproduce this using Thread.Sleep have yielded no results.

```
namespace WoodStockInventorySystem
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A class to store the settings of the program, and a number of relevent methods.
    /// </summary>
    public class SettingsConfiguration
    {
        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// The default list of settings to retrieve from the cache file
        /// </summary>
        public static List<string> listOfSettings = new List<string>
        {
            "LowStockWarning",
            "LowStockThreshold",
            "GeneralThresholdToggle"
        };
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets if the low stock warning is enabled or disabled.
        /// </summary>
        public bool stockWarning { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the point that is globally considered low stock.
        /// </summary>
        public int stockWarningThreshold { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets if the general use threshold is enabled (true) or is the item specific thresholds are enabled (false).
        /// </summary>
        public bool generalThresholdToggle { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the threshold for each item in the open csv file.
        /// </summary>
        public Dictionary<string, int> itemSpecificThresholds { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region Constructors
        /// <summary>
        /// Initialises a new instance of the SettingsConfiguration class with default settings.
        /// </summary>
        public SettingsConfiguration()
        {
            // Exists in the event it is needed in future iterations of the program.
            if (!File.Exists(FilePaths.settingsFile))
            {
                XmlMethods.GenerateNewSettingsFile(FilePaths.settingsFile);
            }

            stockWarning = false;
            stockWarningThreshold = 5;
            generalThresholdToggle = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initialises a new instance of the SettingsConfiguration class with the desired settings retrieved from the file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="settings">The settings to be retrieved from the file.</param>
        public SettingsConfiguration(List<string> settings, DataGridView dataGridView, string settingsFilePath)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(settingsFilePath))
            {
                XmlMethods.GenerateNewSettingsFile(settingsFilePath);
            }

            GetSettings(RetrieveSettingState(settings, settingsFilePath));

            GetItemsForThresholds(dataGridView, settingsFilePath);
        }
        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Applies settings retrieved from the file to an instance of the SettingsConfiguration class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="settingStates">The list of values for each property to be set to.</param>
        private void GetSettings(List<string> settingStates)
        {
            var counter = 0;

            while (counter < settingStates.Count)
            {
                stockWarning = bool.Parse(settingStates[counter]);
                counter++;
                stockWarningThreshold = int.Parse(settingStates[counter]);
                counter++;
                generalThresholdToggle = bool.Parse(settingStates[counter]);
                counter++;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the desired settings from the settingsCache file.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="listOfSettings">The names of the settings to be retrieved.</param>
        /// <returns>A List of strings containing the states of the desired settings.</returns>
        private List<string> RetrieveSettingState(List<string> listOfSettings, string settingsFilePath)
        {
            var settingsOpen = XDocument.Load(settingsFilePath);
            var settingsConfig = settingsOpen.Root.Elements();
            var stateStorage = new List<string>();

            foreach (string setting in listOfSettings)
            {
                stateStorage.Add((from el in settingsConfig
                                  where el.Name.LocalName == setting
                                  select el.Attribute("State").Value).ToList().First());
            }

            return stateStorage;
        }
    
    public void StockWarningToggle(List<string> stockCounts, DataGridView dataGridView, bool toggle)
        {
            if (toggle == true)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < stockCounts.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (int.Parse(stockCounts[i]) < stockWarningThreshold)
                    {
                        dataGridView[2, i].Style = DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    var selectedCell = dataGridView[2, i];

                    selectedCell.Style = DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle;
                }
            }
        }

           /// <summary>
        /// Checks to see if there are any items that the program has not seen before, adding them to the settingsCache file with a default threshold value if they are new.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="tableLayoutPanel">
        /// The TableLayoutPanel from which thresholds are retrieved.
        /// </param>
        public void GetItemsForThresholds(DataGridView dataGridView, string settingsFilePath)
        {
            #region Declaring Variables
            var settingsOpen = XDocument.Load(settingsFilePath);
            var thresholdSpecifics = settingsOpen.Root.Element("ItemSpecificLowStockThresholds").Elements();
            var thresholdSpecificNames = (from threshold in thresholdSpecifics
                                          select threshold.Attribute("ItemName").Value).ToList();
            var currentItems = new List<string>();

            for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)
            {
                if (dataGridView[1, i].Value != null)
                    currentItems.Add(dataGridView[1, i].Value.ToString());
            }

            var newItems = currentItems.Except(thresholdSpecificNames);

            var itemThresholdStorage = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            #endregion

            if (newItems != null)
            {
                foreach (string item in newItems)
                {
                    var newThreshold = new XElement("Threshold",
                        new XAttribute("ItemName", item),
                        new XAttribute("Threshold", 5));
                    settingsOpen.Root.Element("ItemSpecificLowStockThresholds").Add(newThreshold);
                }
                settingsOpen.Save(settingsFilePath);
            }

            foreach (string item in currentItems)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    var tempStorage = (from el in thresholdSpecifics
                                       where el.Attribute("ItemName").Value == item
                                       select el).First();
                    itemThresholdStorage.Add(item, int.Parse(tempStorage.Attribute("Threshold").Value));
                }
            }
            
            itemSpecificThresholds = itemThresholdStorage;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Controls whether or not items with stock counts below individualy defined thresholds are highlighted.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="stockCounts">A Dictionary containing the names and current counts of all items in the current file.</param>
        /// <param name="toggle">A value determining if the feature is being enabled or disabled.</param>
        /// <param name="tableLayoutPanel">The TableLayoutPanel where the text boxes are contained.</param>
        public void StockWarningIndividualThresholds(Dictionary<string, int> stockCounts, DataGridView dataGridView, bool toggle, string settingsFilePath)
        {
            // Disable general threshold
            if (toggle == false)
            {
                #region Declaring Variables
                var settingsOpen = XDocument.Load(settingsFilePath);
                var thresholdSpecifics = settingsOpen.Root.Element("ItemSpecificLowStockThresholds").Elements().ToList();
                var thresholdDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                var currentItems = new List<string>();
                for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (dataGridView[1, i].Value != null)
                        currentItems.Add(dataGridView[1, i].Value.ToString());
                }

                foreach (XElement threshold in thresholdSpecifics)
                {
                    if (currentItems.Contains(threshold.Attribute("ItemName").Value))
                    {
                        thresholdDictionary.Add(threshold.Attribute("ItemName").Value, int.Parse(threshold.Attribute("Threshold").Value));
                    }
                }
                #endregion

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> stockItem in stockCounts)
                {
                    var threshold = thresholdDictionary[stockItem.Key];
                    
                    if (stockItem.Value < threshold)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)
                        {
                            var selectedCell = dataGridView[1, i];
                            if (selectedCell.Value != null)
                            {
                                if (selectedCell.Value.ToString() == stockItem.Key)
                                {
                                    var selectedCountCell = dataGridView[2, i];
                                    selectedCountCell.Style = DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (stockWarning == false)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < dataGridView.RowCount - 1; i++)
                {
                    var selectedCell = dataGridView[2, i];

                    selectedCell.Style = DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle;
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This method makes any necessary changes to the settingsCache file.
        /// </summary>
        public void UpdateSettingsCache(string settingsFilePath)
        {
            var settingsOpen = XDocument.Load(settingsFilePath);
            var settingsContent = settingsOpen.Root.Elements();
            var thresholdSpecifics = settingsOpen.Root.Element("ItemSpecificLowStockThresholds").Elements();
            var changeFinder = (from el in settingsContent
                                where el.Name.LocalName == "LowStockWarning"
                                select el).First();
            changeFinder.Attribute("State").Value = stockWarning.ToString();

            changeFinder = (from el in settingsContent
                            where el.Name.LocalName == "LowStockThreshold"
                            select el).First();
            changeFinder.Attribute("State").Value = stockWarningThreshold.ToString();

            changeFinder = (from el in settingsContent
                            where el.Name.LocalName == "GeneralThresholdToggle"
                            select el).First();
            changeFinder.Attribute("State").Value = generalThresholdToggle.ToString();

            foreach (XElement threshold in thresholdSpecifics)
            {
                var thresholdchangeFinder = from el in thresholdSpecifics
                                            where itemSpecificThresholds.ContainsKey(threshold.Attribute("ItemName").Value)
                                            select el;

                foreach (XElement element in thresholdchangeFinder)
                {
                    if (itemSpecificThresholds.ContainsKey(element.Attribute("ItemName").Value))
                        element.Attribute("Threshold").Value = itemSpecificThresholds[element.Attribute("ItemName").Value].ToString();
                }
            }
            settingsOpen.Save(settingsFilePath);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried everything that I can think of, including stepping through the test method manually (both when run from the test method, and when run normally from vs), and adjusting most of the values to no effect. The fact the it still works sometimes has left me at a loss. If any more details are needed, I would be happy to provide them.

Edit: Now show full contents of the SettingsConfiguration class. (I tried to get the indentation properly formatted so it looks exactly like the .cs file, but if it looks a bit wrong, I did my best. Also, sorry if this is too much information, I just was not entirely sure what was relevant.)

Comment: The test times out after 1 minute. I can't say what exactly happen after that timeout, probably the object instances get collected and any further debugging doesn't makes sense. You can increase the timeout if you want by applying a TimeoutAttribute to the method.

Comment: Do you mean to say that your test takes longer than a minute? What on earth is it doing? How many billion values is it looking through in your grid?

Comment: Maybe a daft question, but how high is the grid, visually? How many rows can you see in it at once?

Comment: As it's an academic exercise, can you test something else and still pass?

Comment: The thing with it taking a minute is only when I'm paused in debug mode, and that was the only thing that I could think of that would maybe cause it to pass. It normally only takes around 0.2 seconds. As for the height of the grid, it is at its default values, not sure exactly what those are though. And I have been considering just making a new pair of test methods, and it's kinda just sunk cost at this point.

Comment: `The error occurs within the settingsConfig.StockWarningToggle method` Could you provide more related code about 'SettingsConfiguration'?

Comment: IMHO it doesn't make much sense debugging the test method longer than the default timeout of 1 minute. Any exception raised afterwards is uninteresting.

Comment: I provided the entire file of the SettingsConfiguration class, because I was unsure exactly how much, and what parts would be needed. And regarding the time out, I had honestly forgotten about that when I was doing the debugging. I'm still relatively new to C# and programming in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured it out. It was something to do with the fact that I was placing the data into a DataView, and then binding that to the DataGridView, as opposed to putting it into the DataGridView directly. (I also noticed that I messed up my assert statements, so I not only missed a row, but checked one that did not exist.) I have no clue why this made it function, only that it did.

I have included the functioning code below if anyone is interested, or has had the same issue as me.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void GeneralStockWarningNonStandardNumbers()
        {
            var stockcounts = new List<string>() 
            {
                "-1",
                "0",
                "1",
                "2",
                "3",
                "4",
                "5",
                "6",
                "7",
                "8",
                "9",
                "10"
            };
            var tempForm = new Form();
            var tempDataGrid = new DataGridView();
            var settingsConfig = new SettingsConfiguration(SettingsConfiguration.listOfSettings, tempDataGrid, TestFilePaths.settingsFile);
            tempDataGrid.ColumnCount = 4;

            tempDataGrid.Columns[0].Name = "Item Code";
            tempDataGrid.Columns[0].ValueType = Type.GetType("System.String");

            tempDataGrid.Columns[1].Name = "Item Description";
            tempDataGrid.Columns[1].ValueType = Type.GetType("System.String");

            tempDataGrid.Columns[2].Name = "Current Count";
            tempDataGrid.Columns[2].ValueType = Type.GetType("System.String");


            tempDataGrid.Columns[3].Name = "On Order";
            tempDataGrid.Columns[3].ValueType = Type.GetType("System.String");

            foreach (var stockItem in stockcounts)
            {
                string[] Row = { "", "", stockItem.ToString(), "" };
                tempDataGrid.Rows.Add(Row);
            }

            tempForm.Controls.Add(tempDataGrid);

            settingsConfig.StockWarningToggle(stockcounts, tempDataGrid, true);

            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 0].Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 1].Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 2].Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 3].Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 4].Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 5].Style == DataGridStyles.LowStockStyle);
            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 6].Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 7].Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 8].Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 9].Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 10].Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
            Assert.IsTrue(tempDataGrid[2, 11].Style == DataGridStyles.SufficientStockStyle);
        }
```

I would also like to thank all the people who commented on this question for their time in helping me, even if it didn't directly lead to a solution. Your input is much appreciated!